# Change Django date time field auto_now_add format

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

I want to know if there is any way to change Django **dateTimeField** format, I want to set the time using `auto_now_add` attribute but I can't get it to save it with the format I want. I know that there is a way suing `models.DateField` but I need to use `auto_now_add`. Thanks

Comment: You could change the format when retrieving the data, rather than saving it like that.... datefield with auto_now_add would be datetime.date() object. you could convert it while you are retrieving it...

Comment: I'm using REST Framework, can I do it there too ? (in the serializer)

Comment: Yes, you could do something like this.. `time = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` or whatever format you want.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it would help any one in the future but here's the answer :

I had to change the field in my model to `created = models.DateField(blank=False, auto_now_add=True)` and create a new field in the serializer class like this (on top of the Meta class) `created = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)`, that worked quite fine.